# How can i maintain position in recycler adapter when removing an item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler adapter, in the view item there is a delete button (del).
I use the following code in click event.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) 
{   
    holder.del.setTag(position);
    holder.del.setOnClickLintener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            int pos= (int) v.getTag();
            //remove view item
            notifyItemRemoved(pos);
            //remove equivalent arraylist item
            listitems.remove(pos);  
        }
    });
}
```

This does not update the tag values in the view items i assume because the `onBindViewHolder()` is not called for the already existing items. How can i update the values or is there a different approach to this.

Comment: try once, first remove the item from a list than notify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the item from the list and then you have to call `notifyItemRemoved(pos)`.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) 
{   
    holder.del.setTag(position);
    holder.del.setOnClickLintener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            int pos = (int) v.getTag();
            //remove equivalent arraylist item
            listitems.remove(pos);  
            //remove view item
            notifyItemRemoved(pos);


           new Handler().postDelayed( new Runnable(){
                @override
                void run(){
                notifyDatasetChanged ()
               }
            },400);

        }
    });
}
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: sorry to get back so late. But what you suggested does not work. onBind is still not called on the existing items.

Comment: Call notifyDatasetChanged also to update all the items in the adapter. See the update answer

Comment: I know calling  notifyDatasetChanged(); will fix the issue, but this also seems to cancel the animation shown for notifyItemRemoved(pos);

Comment: If animation is  the only problem for you the. Use handler to delay the adapter change. See the updated answer

Comment: I am accepting this as solution , as it seems to be the only way for now. Using Handler to call notifydatasetchanged() after 500 ms.

Comment: Hi @Deepak, you'll need both `notifyItemRemoved()` and `notifyItemRangeChanged()`. See my article for detailed tutorial: https://ericntd.medium.com/advanced-recyclerview-insertion-and-deletion-how-to-maintain-position-aebc0b0b5327

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the position as the tag if you want to use notifyItemRemoved and keep the removing animation. Use the Object in your items as the tag and find it when you need the index.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) 
{   
    Object item = listitems.get(position);
    holder.del.setTag(item);
    holder.del.setOnClickLintener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Object item = (Object) v.getTag();
            int pos = listitems.indexOf(item);
            if (pos >= 0) {
             //remove equivalent arraylist item
             listitems.remove(pos);
             //remove view item
             notifyItemRemoved(pos);
           }   
        }
    });
}
```